# Как получить base (source) у варианта префаба в рантайме?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Использую Unity 2020.1.17f1 и C#.

Предположим у меня есть префаб "Предмет". У него есть разные варианты, например, один из них - "Бутылка", у которой, в свою очередь, есть вариант "Газировка".

И вот в коде на C# у меня есть экземпляр "Газировки" как `GameObject`. Можно ли как-нибудь узнать чьим вариантом является эта "Газировка"? Другими словами, хотелось бы получить в рантайме ее `base` (aka `source`), который виден в Unity.

Если это нельзя сделать напрямую(о чем я и подозреваю), то можно ли как-нибудь сделать это обходным путем, например, через реализацию каких-то компонент или не в рантайме?

Примечание: префабы хранятся в формате YAML, читаемы

Comment: По идее, у вас должны быть соответствующие классы. Предмет ---- Бутылка ----- Газировка. Ну или какая-то сущность что хранит в себе родителя и наследника\наследников

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать [PrefabUtility.GetCorrespondingObjectFromSource](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/PrefabUtility.GetCorrespondingObjectFromSource.html), однако данный метод работает только с редактором Unity.

Также расскажу о другом способе который использовался мной до нахождения метода, описанного выше. Если вдруг префабы в формате YAML (как в случае у автора вопроса), можно вручную сканировать `.prefab` файлы как текстовые, искать у них строку с `m_SourcePrefab`, вытаскивать из него значение `guid`, а позже, используя `AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath()` и `AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath()` получить сам объект по `guid`.